# django subquery with a join in it

Tags: django, join, subquery

I've got django 1.8.5 and Python 3.4.3, and trying to create a subquery that constrains my main data set - but the subquery itself (I think) needs a join in it. Or maybe there is a better way to do it.

Here's a trimmed down set of models:

```
class Lot(models.Model):
    lot_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Lot_Country(models.Model):
    lot = models.ForeignKey(Lot)
    country = CountryField()

class Discrete(models.Model):
    discrete_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    master_id = models.ForeignKey(Inventory_Master)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    lot = models.ForeignKey(Lot)
```

I am filtering on various attributes of Discrete (which is discrete supply) and I want to go "up" through Lot, over the Lot_Country, meaning "I only want to get rows from Discrete if the Lot associated with that row has an entry in Lot_Country for my appropriate country (let's say US.)

I've tried something like this:

```
oklots=list(Lot_Country.objects.filter(country='US'))
```

But, first of all that gives me the **str** back, which I don't really want (and changed it to be lot_id, but that's a hack.)

What's the best way to constrain Discrete through Lot and over to Lot_Country? In SQL I would just join in the subquery (or even in the main query - maybe that's what I need? I guess I don't know how to join up to a parent then down into that parent's other child...)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "it gives me the str back"... `Lot_Country.objects.filter(country='US')` will return a queryset. Of course if you print it in your console, you will see a string.

I also think your models need refactoring. The way you have currently defined it, you can associate **multiple** `Lot_Country`s with **one** `Lot`, and a country can only be associated with **one** lot.

If I understand your general model correctly that isn't what you want - you want to associate multiple `Lot`s with one `Lot_Country`. To do that you need to reverse your foreign key relationship (i.e., put it inside the `Lot`).

Then, for fetching all the `Discrete` lots that are in a given country, you would do:

```
discretes_in_us = Discrete.objects.filter(lot__lot_country__country='US')
```

Which will give you a queryset of all `Discretes` whose `Lot` is in the US.